# How do I use a TabView with a NavigationView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, swift5, ios-navigationview

I'm having the exact same issue like the person who posted this question:

[NavigationView doesn't display correctly when using TabView in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779387/navigationview-doesnt-display-correctly-when-using-tabview-in-swiftui#)

Am I doing anything wrong or is it just a SwiftUI bug that'll be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NavigationView doesn't display correctly when using TabView in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57779387/navigationview-doesnt-display-correctly-when-using-tabview-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)` to your TabView/ Top view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            HomePageView()
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
                .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .font(.title)
                .tabItem {
                    VStack {
                        Image(systemName: "bell.fill")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                }
                .tag(1)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
```